# How do i delete individual particles

Tags: modeling, particles

[image]

When I try deleting the sprinkles on the left it also deletes the others

Comment: Hi :). Just disable the *Sprinkles* collection using the checkmark. This will hide it in viewport and render.

Comment: I do it by either masking out the undesired particles (see pic) or by removing the faces or parts of the emitter that produces them. (see video)

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg0F_aG_HlwziLm0c?e=Wd59r8